# Passing char* to pthread crashing

Tags: c, char, pthreads, coredump

I am trying to get a time-based pooling system with threads. I managed to pull this off using fork(), now I am trying to implement it using threads. The timer thread seems to work fine, but for some reason I cannot pass a char* array to the thread (dumping core).

Note: If I try to exit the thread with status 0, I get no warning about giving an integer to a function returning void*. BUT, when I am trying to return something else, let it be 1, I get a warning. I tried to cast them to void*, but with no impact.

Now, for some code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define COUNTING_SUCCESS 0
#define POOLING_SUCCESS 1

int size = 3;

void *count(void *bound_arg){
    int index = 0;
    int *bound = (int*)bound_arg;
    printf("Counting started...\n");
    while(index < *bound){
        printf("You have %d seconds left\n",*bound - index);
        sleep(1);
        index++;
    }

    printf("Time's up!\n");
    pthread_exit(COUNTING_SUCCESS);
}

void *pool(void *questions_ptr){
    char *questions = (char*)questions_ptr;
    char *answer = calloc(sizeof(char*)*size,size);
    for(int i =0 ; i < size ; i++){
        printf("%s : ",questions[i]);
        scanf("%s",&answer);
    }
    pthread_exit(0);

}

int main(){
    char* questions[] = {"Q1","Q2","Q3"};
    int limit = 3 ;
    int *countingLimit = &limit;
    void *countingStatus;
    void *poolingStatus;


    pthread_t timerThread;
    int threadID = pthread_create(&timerThread,NULL,count,(void*)countingLimit);
    pthread_join(timerThread,&countingStatus);
    printf("%d\n",(int*)countingStatus);

    pthread_t poolingThread;
    int poolingThreadID = pthread_create(&poolingThread,NULL,pool,(void*)questions);
    pthread_join(poolingThread,&poolingStatus);
    printf("%d\n",(int*)poolingStatus);



}
```

Sample output:

```
Counting started...
You have 3 seconds left
You have 2 seconds left
You have 1 seconds left
Time's up!
0
Segmentation fault (core dumped) //this is where i try to pass the char*
```

I cannot get it to enter the function.

P.S. I am building the executable using:

```
gcc -o pool pool.c -pthread
```

Comment: `char **questions`. Didn't you get any compiler warnings?

Comment: `gdb` is your friend (in this and other similar cases).

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`

Comment: This isn't right: `printf("%d\n",(int*)countingStatus);`

Comment: Then how am I supposed to get the exit value of a thread ? I know it returns void*.  Can you please be more explicit ?

Comment: @CyberFox: You're returning an `int` not an `int *`, so you want to cast it to `int`, not `int *`...  (or perhaps `intptr_t`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with threads.  You are passing a single `char` to printf where is it expecting a `char *` (for a string), so it crashes:

```
printf("%s : ",questions[i]);
```

you've declared `quesstions` as a `char *` (a single string), so you're fetching a single `char` that will then get treated as a bogus pointer by printf and crash.

You probably intended to declare `questions` as `char **`, as that is what you are passing in as the pthread argument:

```
char **questions = (char**)questions_ptr;
```